# what is the word for "criticizing mildly"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I use rebuke, reprimand, reproach, castigate, censure, and the others in a situation were applicable. but when I have to convey a message that my disapproval or criticism is mild or gentle or not that severe, what should I use?

Comment: How about playing around with the words you use ? For e.g., instead of saying 'This is bad, definitely could've been done better' you could try something along the lines of 'Seems reasonable, but it would be better with some tweaks'.
I think that it is always better to sugar coat your criticism when you want it to be mild or gentle, instead of using a single word for that.

Comment: You already have a suitable candidate in “mildly criticise”. Some would **take a dim view** of the eternal ELU quest to find a single word for a complex subject. I suppose this is a somewhat more worthy goal than finding a 4-letter word with that meaning, but now we’re verging on **damning with faint praise**.

Comment: "damning with faint praise" is brilliantly expressed

Comment: "Chide" would be one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *to make a few comments on something* if I want to criticise mildly something.

Answer (score 1):

My milder synonyms would be

- Advice
- Inform
- Suggest
- Make aware

Answer (score 0):

Consider the option to think more specifically about what is wrong with the object of your mild criticism and why it is wrong. Try to think in precise terms and then use the verb that describes the problem. For example, perhaps someone generally describes something accurately, but also presents some falsehoods in the presentation. In this case, you could mildly criticize the presentation with the verb "disabuse" e.g., "Readers will learn from the presentation, but need to be disabused of the following : . . ."

Answer (score 0):

displeased

but it sometimes works better to use a negative description with the emotion.
Less than pleased, not quite satisfied, not completely confident.